# Google GA4 Event Conversions showing in decimal instead of round number

Tags: google-analytics

Google GA4 Event Conversions  showing in decimal instead of round number

[image]

**It should be like this**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On encountering the same 'issue' I dove into the GA4 docs and I've found that it has to do with the Attribution model. Mine is set to the `Data-driven` attribution model and this can break down the credit to more than one interaction.

I've found [this example](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/6259715#:%7E:text=data%2Ddriven%20attribution-,Example,-You%20own%20a) found in GA4 documentation to be useful;

---

You own a restaurant called Ristorante Abigaille in Florence, Italy. A customer finds your site by clicking on your ads after performing each of these searches: "restaurant tuscany," "restaurant florence," "3 star restaurant florence," and then "3 star restaurant abigaille florence." She makes a reservation after clicking on your ad that appeared with "3 star restaurant abigaille florence."

- In the "Last click" attribution model, the last keyword, "3 star restaurant abigaille florence," would receive 100% of the credit for the conversion.
  In the "First click" attribution model, the first keyword, "restaurant tuscany," would receive 100% of the credit for the conversion.
- In the "Linear" attribution model, each keyword would share equal credit (25% each) for the conversion.
- In the "Time decay" attribution model, the keyword "3 star restaurant abigaille florence" would receive the most credit because it was searched closest to the conversion. The "restaurant tuscany" keyword would receive the least credit since it was searched first.
- In the "Position-based" attribution model, "restaurant tuscany" and "3 star restaurant abigaille florence" would each receive 40% credit, while "restaurant florence" and "3 star restaurant florence" would each receive 10% credit.
- In the "Data-driven" attribution model, each keyword would receive part of the credit, depending on how much it contributed to driving the conversion.

---

More documentation;

- [Decimals in conversion data](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/6270625?hl=en#:%7E:text=Decimals%20in%20conversion%20data)
- [About the different attribution models](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/6259715#:%7E:text=About%20the%20different%20attribution%20models) (same page as example above)
- [About data-driven attribution](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/6394265) focused on the data-driven attribution model

Comment: thanks for the feedback yes after changing Attribute Setting  To -> Data-driven it's working fine.